# How to get wrapped func.__code__.co_filename with decorator?

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, python-decorators

A simple folder structure shown below, and all the functions in test.py have keyword decorator on it.

```
 lib
  |--- keyword.py
 main
  |--- test.py
```

Keyword.py

```
from functools import wraps
def keyword(name=None, tags=(), types=()):

    def _method_wrapper(func):

        @wraps(func)
        def _passargs(self, *args, **kwargs):  
            print(func.__code__.co_filename)  # --> '..\main\test.py'
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

        print(_passargs.__code__.co_filename)  # --> '..\lib\keyword.py'
                
        return _passargs

    return _method_wrapper
```

*notes: `print(..)` is just an example, I need both `_passargs` & `func` to have the same code object, instead of printing another variable :)*

As you can see, the `_passargs` got the wrong `co_filename`.

This is from `robotframework` keyword.py, and I modified it for my own purpose. However I failed to figure out how to make both `_passargs` & `func` have the correct source file location so the `robot.libdoc` can generate doc.libspec correctly.

Can anyone help?

**The expectation**

```
func.__code__.co_filename = '..\main\test.py'
_passargs.__code__.co_filename = '..\main\test.py'
```

Python version = 3.8.10

Comment: Try `func.__wrapped__.__code__.co_filename` instead. You can do something like `try: func = func.__wrapped except AttributeError: pass` if you aren't sure whether `func` is decorated or not.

Comment: Hi @kaya3, sorry for the lack of explanation that causes your misunderstanding. 
I actually need `_passargs` to return correct `__code__` attribute but not only want to print it! The robot.libdoc is a function which will generate info of keywords during initializing classes, and it won't go into `_passargs` but only `_method_wrapper` at the time. Therefore, I need `_passargs` return the actually `__code__.co_filename` at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here to help ppl who may struggle with the same issue.

The original decorator func:

```
from functools import wraps
def keyword(name=None, tags=(), types=()):

    def _method_wrapper(func):

        @wraps(func)
        def _passargs(self, *args, **kwargs):  
            print(func.__code__.co_filename)  # --> '..\main\test.py'
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

        print(_passargs.__code__.co_filename)  # --> '..\lib\keyword.py'
                
        return _passargs

    return _method_wrapper
```

Most of the time, we only needs the last level of decorator (`return func(self, *args, **kwargs)` in this example) to return the proper attributes of the wrapped func.

However, in my case, there's a function which will scan all the functions with this `keyword` decorator during initializing class. And it won't go into `def _passargs` level due to we didn't provide any arguments but just trying to get the wrapped func (`return _passargs`) related attributes.

To resolve this issue, we can only override the `co_filename` at RUNTIME.

Here's the solution to override `__code__` object in decorator.

```
from types import CodeType
from functools import wraps


def keyword(name=None, tags=(), types=()):

    def _method_wrapper(func):

        @wraps(func)
        def _passargs(self, *args, **kwargs):  
            print(func.__code__.co_filename)  # --> '..\main\test.py'
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

        fix_co_filename(_passargs, func.__code__.co_filename)
        print(_passargs.__code__.co_filename)  # --> '..\main\test.py'
                
        return _passargs

    return _method_wrapper 


def fix_co_filename(func, co_filename):
    fn_code = func.__code__
    func.__code__ = CodeType(
        fn_code.co_argcount,
        fn_code.co_posonlyargcount,
        fn_code.co_kwonlyargcount,
        fn_code.co_nlocals,
        fn_code.co_stacksize,
        fn_code.co_flags,
        fn_code.co_code,
        fn_code.co_consts,
        fn_code.co_names,
        fn_code.co_varnames,
        co_filename,
        fn_code.co_name,
        fn_code.co_firstlineno,
        fn_code.co_lnotab,
        fn_code.co_freevars,
        fn_code.co_cellvars)
```